# react-native - TouchableHighlight - onPress - pass Parameter - if i pass the iterator var it is every time the highest number

Tags: react-native, iteration, touchablehighlight

how i can pass successfull and id for which touchable is passed.

```
for(var i = 0; i < datasource.length;i++){

var currentIndex = i;
this.viewCollection.push(

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handleItemTouch(currentIndex)} >

</TouchableHighlight>

 );
}

  handleItemTouch(i) {
  //i is every time equal to datasource.length
```

//based on "i" i want to scroll somewhere
    }

what i want to do is, that based on which touchablehighlight is pressed to scroll the scrollview to a x coordinate based on the "i" parameter

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using var, the currentIndex variable isn't block scoped.

For example the first iteration will set the `currentIndex` to 1, so if you click on the touchablehighlight...it will be the correct index, but for every iteration after it will be updating the `currentIndex` on all the touchablehighlights.

This is why currentIndex will always be the length of the datasource on anyone of them you click. You can fix this by using `let` or if you use an iterator like forEach/map which will have different execution contexts.

```
for (let i = 0; i < datasource.length; i++){

this.viewCollection.push(

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handleItemTouch(i)} >

</TouchableHighlight>

 );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind` for these matters. For example

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleItemTouch.bind(this, currentIndex)} ></TouchableHighlight>
```

And then on your handleItemTouch:

```
handleItemTouch(index) {
    //do stuff
}
```